# Is My Query correct?

Tags: objectify

I am trying to query using objectify to display a list of `<Fight>` with eventEid = 111. Is the below call correct? I ran it and it returns 0... but its strange because it looks right

Please note that eventEid is a long. Does that affect the query?

```
ofy().load().type(Fight.class).filter("eventEid", 111).list();
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that *eventEid* is indexed property.

> Filtering on unindexed properties returns no results.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Filters